# Cannot open PDF on iPad 4 iOS10

Tags: javascript, ipad, pdf, uiwebview, ios10

I have created a simple web-application with the functionality of opening pdfs, while clicking on the buttons.

In order to be viewable on iPad I have wrapped my web-application to UIWebView but, unfortunately, if I bind opening PDF on 'touchend' event, I cannot open PDF files, although if I bind opening PDF to click event - it works well.

But, when I open my web-application in the iframe this CSS rule somehow influence on window.open behavior:

```
-webkit-user-select: none;
```

if the user selection is allowed, pdf is opened after text on the button is selected.

So, there is a sample of my web-application below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <button style="width: 100%; height: 110px;">Open PDF (ontouchend)</button>
    <button style="width: 100%; height: 110px;">Open PDF (onclick)</button>

    <script>

        function openPdf() {
            window.open("./sample.pdf", "_blank");
        }

        var el1 = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
        var el2 = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[1];

        el1.addEventListener("touchend", openPdf, false); // cannot open pdf, window.open returns 'undefined'
        el2.addEventListener("click", openPdf, false); // works as expected

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `-webkit-user-select: none;` means any interaction on the element is ignored, and events will be not be triggered (and bubbled) from the element. Instead, events will be triggered (and bubbled, again) from whatever sits behind the element.